# Missing manifest.json file in angular 12

Tags: angular

I have created an angular application when i start it using `ng serve` and check it in browser i'm getting this error in console:

> GET http://localhost:4200/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)
> manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

I searched in the project directory but couldn't found this manifest.json file.

This is the screenshot of console of web browser

[image]

Project Structure:

[image]

Any solution to resolve this issue

Thanks

Comment: please check [this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/manifest.json+404+%28not+found%29)

Comment: @KiranMistry:  I'm running complete angular application through `ng serve` on my local system and if i copy only dist folder on server then also i get this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when you create a new project, Angular doesn't create the `manifest.json` file.

It looks like from some part of your project you're trying to request the file, but since it's not in your project it cannot find it and throws you the error.

Try to check if your `src/index.html` has something like:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

You can remove it to suppress the error. But if you really need to turn your app into PWA, then it's recommended to use the `@angular/pwa` package:

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

It will do all the job for you and will initialize the manifest file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i have checked there is a code `  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">` in src/index.html will installing `ng add @angular/pwa`  will resolve this issue? i want web app only

Comment: @user3653474 then you can just remove the line in your index.html

Comment: Thanks i will comment it out

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure your `angular.json` file includes `manifest.json` under `assets`, like this:

```
"assets": [
...
  "src/manifest.json",
...
]
```

Mine was missing and hence the 404 in the browser.